# Difficulties with some applications of Nakayama's lemma in Shafarevich's "Basic Algebraic Geometry I"

Tags: algebraic-geometry

In a proof in "Basic Algebraic Geometry I", Shafarevich applies Nakayama's lemma on two occasions. I'm not sure how the conclusions reached follow from the lemma.

Nakayama's lemma states:

> Let $ M $ be a finite module over a ring $ A $ and $ \mathfrak{a} \subset A $ an ideal. Suppose that for any element $ a \in 1 + \mathfrak{a}, \; aM = 0 $ implies $ M = 0. $ Then $ \mathfrak{a}M = M $ implies that $ M = 0. $

The result being proved is the following:

> A finite map $ f $ from a variety $ X $ is an isomorphic embedding if and only if it is one-to-one and $ d_{x}f $ is an isomorphic embedding of the tangent space $ \Theta_{x} $ for every $ x \in X. $

The author sets $ f(X) = Y $ and $ \varphi = f^{-1}, $ and notes that the result will be proved if we show that $ \varphi $ is a regular map. Let $ y \in Y. $

Fast forwarding to the first difficulty, consider the following passage:

> The second hypothesis of the lemma is that $ f^{*}:\mathfrak{m}_{y}/\mathfrak{m}_{y}^{2} \rightarrow \mathfrak{m}_{x}/\mathfrak{m}_{x}^{2} $ is surjective. In other words, if $ \mathfrak{m}_{y} = (u_{1},\dots,u_{k}), $ then the elements $ f^{*}(u_{i}) + \mathfrak{m}_{x}^{2} $ generate $ \mathfrak{m}_{x}/\mathfrak{m}_{x}^{2}. $ We apply Nakayama's lemma to $ \mathfrak{m}_{x} $ as an $ \mathcal{O}_{x}$-module. It then follows from this that $ \mathfrak{m}_{x} = (f^{*}(u_{1}),\dots,f^{*}(u_{k})), $ or in other words $$ \mathfrak{m}_{x} = f^{*}(\mathfrak{m}_{y})\mathcal{O}_{x}.  $$

The second difficulty stems from the following:

> Now apply Nakayama's lemma to $ \mathcal{O}_{x} $ as a $ f^{*}(\mathcal{O}_{y})$-module. The equality above shows that $$ \mathcal{O}_{x}/f^{*}(\mathfrak{m}_{y})\mathcal{O}_{x} = \mathcal{O}_{x}/\mathfrak{m}_{x} = k, $$ and hence is generated by the single element $ 1. $ It follows by Nakayama's lemma that $ \mathcal{O}_{x} = f^{*}(\mathcal{O}_{y}). $

I have attempted to apply the lemma, but I am sure I am wrong.

Let $ a = f^{*}(\mathcal{O}_{y}), \mathfrak{a} = f^{*}(\mathfrak{m}_{y}), M = \mathcal{O}_{x} $ and $ a = 1 + f^{*}(g), $ where $ g \in \mathfrak{m}_{y}. $

$$ (1+f^{*}(g))\mathcal{O}_{x} = \mathcal{O}_{x} + f^{*}(g)\mathcal{O}_{x} = \mathcal{O}_{x}/f^{*}(g)\mathcal{O}_{x}. $$

According to the lemma, $$ (1 + f^{*}(g))\mathcal{O}_{x} =  \mathcal{O}_{x}/f^{*}(g)\mathcal{O}_{x} = \mathcal{O}_{x} \Longrightarrow    \mathcal{O}_{x} = f^{*}(g)\mathcal{O}_{x}. $$

I feel that I'm off the mark, but I'm not sure how.